# Not being able to type into form input on IE11

Tags: html, css, forms, input, internet-explorer-11

Good morning

We are displaying a third party CRM form into our page, in Chrome and Firefox the forms works just fine, in IE11 we are not being able to type into the input boxes, and the cursor blinks outside of the input. The textarea works fine, also

This is an input sample of an input:

```
<div class="moonray-form-element-wrapper moonray-form-element-wrapper-contracted moonray-form-element-wrapper-alignment-left moonray-form-input-type-text">
<label for="mr-field-element-542548807807" class="moonray-form-label"></label>
<input name="firstname" type="text" class="moonray-form-input moonray-form-state-active" id="mr-field-element-542548807807" required="" value="" placeholder="NAME" data-required="true"></div>
```

Has anyone had troubles with this one?

Do I need to provide more information for you to figure this out?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked in the "console" section of IE11's developer tools (press F12) to see if there are any JavaScript errors being reported? Can you type text where the cursor is? - which would suggest that where the input is and where it is rendered are separate.

Comment: Looks there's some padding applied, can I have css for the input field?

Comment: There are a couple of JS errors, they don't seem to be related to the issue, for me, at least

When I type in there is no new text anywhere, and the value for the input remains being an empty string. I tried forcing the value for the inputs using javascript, and I was successful on doing so.

I am uploading pictures of the CSS and the input field

https://imgur.com/a/CT8ViPo

Here they are, sorry if I'm not using the tools to share my error properly

Comment: Looks like you are displaying the CRM page in an iframe. I suggest directly try to visit the CRM page in the IE and check whether same issue occurs or not. Further, Try to create a sample with the HTML and CSS code that can produce the issue with the IE browser. It can really help us to understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: Thank you guys @Deepak-MSFT

I tried manually changing the input elements to textareas and they work fine that way

The form is loading into the HTML directly, not in an iframe

Thanks guys

Comment: @AndrewMorton Were you able to look at my response?

Comment: @Raphael Were you able to look at the images?

Comment: Yes, have taken a look. Well, nothing obvious - css seems to be fine. Can you remove padding completely for this input field pls? Additionally try to add focus() on mousedown for this input field

Comment: Did you use the same CSS classes with the textarea? If you can give the sample then we can try to make some tests with it.